# HTML in PHP (IMG SRC with variable as URL)

Tags: php, html

I am trying to display an image using a variable "$images" that contains the URL parsed form an API.
This is my code:

```
echo "<td>""<img src='",$image,"'>""</td>\n";
```

I assume there is a typo I cannot detect because I get a blank screen when running this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo "<td>"."<img src='".$image."'>"."</td>";
```

Or

```
echo "<td><img src='".$image."'></td>";
```

You were missing the dots/commas after/before the td tags

Answer (score 1):

use . not ,

```
<img src='".$image."'>
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP requires that you chain your strings together using a `.`

E.g.

```
echo 'Test' . ' ' . 'Hello'; // Test Hello
```

Answer (score 0):

Or simply :

```
echo "<td><img src='$image'></td>";
```

Check **[documentation](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.echo.php)**.